# Is Cov(X,Y|Z).x always positive? (with X,Y,Z, normal random vectors and x>0)

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution, conditional-variance

Let x be a vector of positive values, we know that for multivariate normal distributions of X, Y and Z, $Cov(X,Y|Z)x=(\Sigma_{XZ}-\Sigma_{XY}\Sigma_{YY}^{-1}\Sigma_{YZ})x$ does not depend on the given values $Z=(Z_1,...,Z_n)$ (i.e. is not a random vector). However, is  $Cov(X,Y|Z)x$ a vector of positive values? I do not manage to prove it.

Comment: Why do you expect that to be true?

Comment: Forget $Z,$ because it's irrelevant, and consider the simplest possible non-trivial case where $n=2.$  Write down the $2\times 2$ covariance matrix for *negatively* correlated variables $(Y,Z)$ and apply it to the positive vector $x=(\epsilon,1)^\prime$ for small $\epsilon.$  Draw your conclusions.